# Using an Entry's Added Form in a template in Sprout Forms

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Using Sprout Forms and have added the Form Name > Select a Form to the Entry's field layout.
[image: entry field layout]

After I select a form on this Entry, what do I hook into to get this to display on my template?
[image: selected form in entry]

I know from the documentation that you can specifically pass in the form's Handle `{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm('myForm') }}`, but what do I need to do to get the drop-down form to display if there is one selected?

Comment: Hey David, can you help me understand what you are trying to do here?  Am I correct in thinking that you have a Form that allows a user to create a relationship to another Form? Also, what are you expecting to be displayed in your template?  Would a dropdown field that lists all the Forms you have in Sprout Forms be what you want to output?

Comment: Ignore that last comment.  The question is clear.  I was misreading it.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically display a Form that you've related to an Entry using a Sprout Forms Form relations field you can pass the handle of the form to the `displayForm()` tag in your template:

**_entry.html**

```
{% set formHandle = entry.formFieldHandle.first().handle %}

{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm( formHandle ) }}
```

There is a doc page that describes this here: [Relations Field on Entry Page](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/relations-field-on-entry-page) and depending on where you want to redirect the user after they submit the form, Sprout Forms also supports [relative redirects](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/redirects).